# Unable to browse internet, unless in safe mode with networking

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet, 64-bit, safe-mode

I have tried using Firefox, Chrome, and IE. No programs can connect to the internet. There is one oddity, though: pinging and tracert(ing) 8.8.8.8 (and perhaps any other site) works perfectly fine, despite the lack of other internet accessibility.

Plus, I am connected to WiFi in regular start-up and Windows finds no issues with the internet. I have also tried resetting the router, but that's not the issue, since other devices have no problem with the net.

I have tried `ipconfig release/renew/flushdns` and have ruled out all start-up programs, and all non-Microsoft services. The only thing left are the Microsoft services, and I don't know the exact drivers needed for basic internet and Windows functionality.

If anyone could list the drivers/services needed for internet functionality, and how to manually load drivers (if needed)?

It would be very helpful.

Thank you.

TLDR: Although connected to WiFi, Internet only works in Safe Mode with Networking, however pinging and tracert work fine in *normal mode*. All start-up programs + non-MS services ruled out as the problem.

Windows 7 Home Premium x64
Intel PRO
DirectX 11

Comment: Did you try using c:\> telnet superuser.com 80 and then typing in GET /   ?  You may also want to give [HiJackThis](http://netsecurity.about.com/od/popupsandspyware/a/aahijackthis.htm) to log and see if any software is not allowing you to connect to the internet. Other common software would be things like anti-virus, security software, etc. that is preventing you from connecting to the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Disable addons in the browsers and run a malware scan. You will have to get a copy of Malwarebytes onto a thumbdrive from safe mode.

Also, clear cookies/browser data. Your ability to ping and tracert suggest a healthy network stack so I don't think I'd worry about that too much.

I've seen nasty addons cause this type of behavior and malware will do it too

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Open Command Prompt as Administrator (click Start, type "command prompt" in the search bar, right-click the Command Prompt icon that will appear and choose "Run As Administrator" from the menu).
2. Enter the following commands followed by enter:

   netsh i i r r

   netsh winsock reset

You will be resetting the tcp/ip stack and the winsock catalog. You will need to restart afterwards. That usually fixes the problem. Follow this up with a malware check. Something has messed with your networking stacks.

Comment: While these commends may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.

Comment: `netsh w r` -> The following command was not found: w r.

Comment: i have corrected the command